# Command-line program for printing documents?

Tags: unix, printing

Is there a program that can print to a hardware printer? Sort of like:

```
print -type color -copies 2 sample.pdf
```

Best I could find was Cups (http://www.cups.org/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cups works, in fact.  The command line program it provides is called `lp`.